# Netcat no Linux

Tags: linux

Tentei utilizar o netcat com a opçao -e e o seguinte erro ocorreu;

```
netcat: invalid option -- 'e'
This is nc from the netcat-openbsd package. An alternative nc is available
in the netcat-traditional package.
usage: nc [-46bCDdhjklnrStUuvZz] [-I length] [-i interval] [-O length]
      [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port] [-q seconds] [-s source]
      [-T toskeyword] [-V rtable] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_protocol]
      [-x proxy_address[:port]] [destination] [port]
```

a opcao -e só funciona no kali?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em alguns sistemas operacionais o netcat não tem a opção `-e` por segurança, por isso em alguns casos é necessário criar uma alternativa ao netcat com o python, por exemplo.

Além disso há algumas outras opções que podem funcionar.

De uma olhada nesse artigo:

https://pen-testing.sans.org/blog/2013/05/06/netcat-without-e-no-problem